# Sending password to vpn connection using expect

Tags: svn, passwords, expect

I'm tring to send password to my vpn connection using expect but the password is not sent correctly.
I use the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -d

set pass "myPassword"
spawn snx -g -s 199.203.xxx.xxx -c ~/vpn_connection/file(IL\).p12
match_max 100000
expect "Please enter the certificate's password:"
send "$pass\r"
expect eof
```

I get the error:
"SNX: Connection aborted." which means password is inncorect

Although if I enter the password manually to cmd it works.
Thanks ...

Comment: show the debugging output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `~` char is not special in `Tcl` (and so `Expect`) so your `spawn` command should write like this:

```
# '(' and ')' are not specical in Tcl.
spawn snx -g -s 199.203.xxx.xxx -c $env(HOME)/vpn_connection/file(IL).p12
```

or

```
# But '(' and ')' need to be quoted in shell.
spawn sh -c "snx -g -s 199.203.xxx.xxx -c ~/vpn_connection/file\\(IL\\).p12"
# or
spawn sh -c {snx -g -s 199.203.xxx.xxx -c ~/vpn_connection/file\(IL\).p12}
```